# error with left join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to execute the following, but am receiving this error:

> The objects "Projects" and "Projects" in the FROM clause have the same
>   exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

```
SELECT Project.Name, Project.Client, Business.BType
FROM Project
LEFT JOIN Project ON Project.Name = Business.Name
```

I've got 2 tables - Project and Business.
Project has 2 columns - Name, Client
Business has 2 columns - Name, BType

I want both Project columns shown, and the Business.BType column shown, if it the Business.Name matches with the Project.Name.

Can anyone please guide me on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: try changing `LEFT JOIN Project` to `LEFT JOIN Business`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one you're not selecting anything from the business table, because it's not in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses.

```
FROM Project
LEFT JOIN Project
```

Perhaps you meant

```
FROM Project
LEFT JOIN Business
          ^^^^^^^^
```

instead?